# App Store ERROR-ITMS-9000 - stbuild_template does not have proper alignment

Tags: ios, xcode, extjs

After sending my_app.ipa with the Application Loader I get the error that the app binary stbuild_template does not have proper alignment (ERROR-ITMS-9000: Invalid Segment Alignment).

It says try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode version.

I'm compiling with Sencha Cmd v3.1.2.342.
And I'm using the latest Xcode version 6.1.1 + command line tools 6.1 + iOS 8.1.

In previous uploads (>6 months ago) Apple never complaint about this.

Anybody got a clue?